# Save location for different ways to install gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, directory, rubygems

Are there any differences in the save locations for the following commands?:

```
gem install some_gem
sudo gem install some_gem
bundle install
```

`bundle install` is for rails 3 project.

Will all of them save the installed gem in the same directory or in different directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in different directories, because the "root" user has a different account and path than you do.

Root's access via `sudo` will allow the file to be written to the gem environment for a Ruby in the `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` directories. (Gem won't put the files there, but they'll be associated with a Ruby in one of those directories.)

You don't have access to write to those areas by default, so if you tried to run `gem install`, and only had a System Ruby, you'd probably get permission errors and the attempt should fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How about the bundle install?

Comment: I don't have experience using `bundle` directly, but it has to play by the same rules as all other apps. It can write to areas where you have permission. If you run as yourself it will be into areas of your drive that are owned by you. If you run as `sudo` or `su` to root then you'll assume root's privileges and can write 'most anywhere.

Comment: Re: Bundler: Not exactly. See my answer; bundler installs gems to system.

Comment: Previously I said, "I don't have experience using bundle directly". Actually I should say, "I use '`bundle install`' as part of my Rails 3 setup, but don't use bundle for anything else."

Answer (score 1):

The Tin Man answered `sudo` vs. non-`sudo`, so as for bundler...

Bundler installs gems to the system path (similarly to if they'd been installed by `sudo`)--at least on OSX, though I imagine other OS would be the same.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the "SUDO USAGE" section in Bundle's [bundle-install](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html) docs. Bundle behaves just as any other well-behaved app, and assumes the permissions of the calling user. If it needs to write to a system directory it has to ask for permission, it can't do it itself.

Comment: So using `bundle install` is similar to `sudo gem install` right? BTW, today I just reinstalled anything and re-setup the env again. I found that I couldn't install gem without `sudo`, otherwise it prompts a message saying that it has no permission to write......

Comment: @the Tin Man, I found `--path` and `--system` in the docs you mentioned. Are they corresponds to `gem install` and `sudo gem install`?

Comment: @the Tin Man: That's weird, because bundler installs to my system dir just like `sudo gem install`, while `gem install` puts the files in my user directory.

Comment: It is similar, to a point. Read the "bundle-install" doc I mentioned above. The differences are somewhat subtle until you've run into the side-effects, like you did. :-) In general, if you have to type `sudo` to a command, especially with Ruby or Rails, you should stop and think about what is really happening: In effect you are changing the operating system's version of Ruby and/or Rails, or a protected version of them. Doing so can have long-term side-effects you may not notice until much later. Search SO for questions about RVM, MacPorts and Fink for discussions why sudo is possibly bad.

Comment: @vonconrad, "bundler installs to my system dir just like sudo gem install". If bundler installs to your system without you having specified a sudo or root password, then something is seriously wrong with the security on your system. You might want to run `disk utility` on your drive and let it fix permissions if that is what is really happening. If you are always running as root, which is something newbies sometimes used to do, then DON'T!